# Returning from inside for loop causes type mismatch

Tags: rust, type-mismatch

I am attempting to return a function pointer, which is located inside a `for` loop, from a function located in an `impl` of a struct.

```
fn locate_func(&self, string: &str) -> fn() -> bool {
    let mut func;

    for alt in &self.alts {
        return alt.func;
    }
}
```

There will be an `if` statement inside the `for` loop in the future, but as I am testing things at the very moment, it looks rather generic, and somewhat illogical.

The above code in my mind, is supposed to return the pointer to `alt.func()`, which clearly is a pointer, as it tells me so should I remove the return and semicolon of that line.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:42:3
   |
42 |            for alt in &self.alts
   |            ^ expected fn pointer, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `fn() -> bool`
   = note:    found type `()`
```

Above is the error that is caused upon running `locate_func()`. I am clearly missing something as the aforementioned code is not working properly. Any hints?

Comment: What are you returning if `self.alts` is empty?

Comment: It is guaranteed not to be.

Comment: But that is a good point code-wise.

Comment: *a function located in an impl of a struct* — those are called **methods**.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `for`-loop is the last *expression* inside the function. The compiler expects the last *expression* to evaluate to the return type. But all loops evaluate to `()` (*unit* or *void*), so the compiler has a classic type mismatch there.

The correct question to ask yourself is: what would happen if the `return` inside of the loop wouldn't be executed (for example, because the loop isn't executed at all, because `self.alts` is empty)? This would lead to problems, wouldn't it?

So you have to return a valid object *after* the `for`-loop to cover that case. **But** if you are certain that the spot after the loop will never be reached you can use `unreachable!();` to tell the compiler what you already know. However, if the program will reach this spot, it will panic! So better make sure, you know for certain how the program behaves.

Comment: And in the original case, where there will be an `if` in the loop, I'd advocate for something like `self.alts.iter().find(...).expect("There must be a func")`.