# Returning modified array from for loop without type mismatch

Tags: rust

In pseudo-code, I'm trying to do the following:

```
my_array = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
my_array = array_modify_fn(my_array)

fn array_modify_fn(array) {
    for i in array {
        array[i] = some_operation
    }
}
```

Having read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288979/returning-from-inside-for-loop-causes-type-mismatch) about the type mismatch this kind of loop/function would cause in Rust, I'm still confused as to how to actually implement what I want to implement here, but in Rust.

Am I just going about the problem in the wrong way? (For Rust at least; this is how I would do it in Python.)

My Rust at the moment looks like this:

```
let mut life_array = [[false; SIZE]; SIZE];
life_array = random_init(&mut life_array); // in main function

fn random_init(arr: &mut [[bool; SIZE]; SIZE]) -> [[bool; SIZE]; SIZE] {
    for i in 0 .. (SIZE*SIZE) {
        arr[i/SIZE][i%SIZE] = rand::random()
    }
}
```

and this returns the type mismatch: `expected type '[[bool; SIZE]; SIZE]' found type '()'`

Comment: Do you need to specifically modify the existing array, or is returning a new one what you want? As it is you've got a bit of both since you're taking a mutable reference but then also returning the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined `random_init` with a return type, yet your function doesn't return anything (strictly speaking, it returns `()`). Since you're mutating the array in-place, your function doesn't have to return anything, so you should just omit the return type.

```
const SIZE: usize = 4;

extern crate rand;

fn main() {
    let mut life_array = [[false; SIZE]; SIZE];
    random_init(&mut life_array);
}

fn random_init(arr: &mut [[bool; SIZE]; SIZE]) {
    for i in 0..(SIZE * SIZE) {
        arr[i / SIZE][i % SIZE] = rand::random()
    }
}
```